# Wordpress: how to use a custom registration.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a custom registration.php file which intends to validate form input and submits a new user to the user database. I'm trying to use from a custom Wordpress Page as shown below:

```
<form action="wp-content/plugins/registration/register.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
    </div>
```

The register.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

// Initialise variables
$name = "";
$password = "";
$email = "";
$phone = "";
$how = "";
$type = "";

// Sanitise fields
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $name = test_input($_POST["inputUsername"]);
    $password = test_input($_POST["inputPassword"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["inputEmail"]);
    $phone = test_input($_POST["inputPhone"]);
    $how = test_input($_POST["inputHow"]);
    $type = test_input($_POST["inputType"]);
}
?>
```

I'm struggling to access it - I get a 404 not found. Should I be trying to do custom user registration like this? Or is there a better way? I want to avoid putting all the PHP code in a Page with the HTML.

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should try with **URL** in action rather than giving file path like that.